# React-select address autocomplete appears in Chrome

Tags: react-select

We use react-select in the project and this autocomplete appears when a chrome has saved address. I've tried to use

> autocomplete='chrome-off'

or just

> autocomplete='off'

I've even tried to rewrite styles from scratch follow documentation but it didn't help.

Please, maybe you know what can cause the issue? Thank you in advance

https://share.vidyard.com/watch/a3WZ5Fv7PR9ojfKHvHN4D1

Answer (score 0):

`inputProps={{autoComplete: 'random-string', autofill:'off' }}`

That should take care of your issue. Note that autofill should be lowercase, not camelCase.